# How to populate different category data from the same api at the DOM using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working with news API and trying to populate different category (i.e sports, science, business etc) under different heading on the same page of the website, but failed to do so. Here I tried to use template literal, as first created a template literal in the api named category and initiated it using let. So there are two sections "Trending Blogs" and "You May Like" so here I wanna show two different category in the two different section respectively. Here I'm attaching the code in the following.

Here is the code in html

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/utils.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/navbar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/body.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e582ecfb98.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <h1>This is a blog site</h1> -->
    <!-- Navbar starts from here -->
    <nav class="navigation max-width-0 m-auto">
      <div class="middle">
        <a href="./index.html"><b> Blogsite</b></a>
      </div>
      <div class="left">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="header-elements" href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="header-elements" href="./about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="header-elements" href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Article Search" />
        <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Navbar ends -->
    <!-- body starts  -->
    <div class="content max-width-1 m-auto">
      <h1 class="land-heading">Welcome to Blogsite</h1>
      <p class="intro">
        Atameo allows travellers to capture their trips in a completely new way.
        It records your route, adds your photos, videos and music and turns your
        adventures into your personal travel profile. Have all your travel
        experiences in one place and find out more about your travel style by
        diving into your personal travel statistics: How far did you travel last
        year? What’s the highest point you have been to? How much of the world
        have you seen? Inspire others to go out and explore, while getting
        inspired by some of the most daring journeys of our time. Explore.
        Capture. Inspire.
      </p>
      <hr />
      <h1 class="land-heading">Trending Blogs</h1>
      <div class="blog-section" id="blog-section">
        
      </div>

      <h1 class="land-heading">You may like</h1>
      <div class="blog-section" id="blog-section2">
        
      </div>
      <h1 class="land-heading">Categories</h1>
      <div class="blog-section" id="category">
        <div class="r1c1 block">
            <a href=""
              ><img
                class="img"
                src="https://www.nomadicmatt.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/parisnm3.jpeg"
                alt="img"
              />
              <p class="blog-title">NM+ Weekly Update: Europe Edition</p></a
            >
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Body ends -->
    <!-- Footer starts -->
    <div class="footer m-auto">
      <label for="">Feedback</label>
      <input type="text" class="" placeholder="First Name" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-foot">Send Feedback</button>
    </div>
    <div class="m-auto copyright">
      <p>copyright 2022 @md_arif</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer ends -->
    <script src="./scripts/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`
Here is the code of vanilla-js

```
console.log("Here we go");
let blogSection = document.getElementById("blog-section");
let blogSection2 = document.getElementById("blog-section2");

function generateCards(e) {
  const newXHRRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // let source = 'the-times-of-india';
  let apikey = '75da3b7678de41fcb76359935aabdc3d'
  let category = '';
  newXHRRequest.open(
    "GET",
    `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=${category}&pagesize=3&apiKey=${apikey}`,
    true
  );
  newXHRRequest.getResponseHeader("content-type", "application/json");

  newXHRRequest.onload = function () {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      let myCards = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(myCards);
      let articles = myCards.articles;
        // console.log(articles);
      let itemsHtml = "";
      articles.forEach((element) => {
        // console.log(articles);
        // category="sports";
        
        console.log(element);
        let items = `<div class="r1c1 block">
        <a href="${element["url"]}" target="_blank"><img class="img" src=${element["urlToImage"]} alt="img">
        <p class="blog-title">${element["title"]}</p></a>
        </div>`;
        itemsHtml += items;
      });
      blogSection.innerHTML = itemsHtml;
      blogSection2.innerHTML = itemsHtml;
    } else {
      console.log("Some error occured");
    }
  };
  newXHRRequest.send();
}
generateCards();
```

Comment: Is there an error? or that the 2 sections get same content? Can you post a cut down version of `this.responseText` json?

Comment: There is no error. But I'm trying to populate the two diferent headings known as 'Trending Blogs' and 'You may like' with different categories of news from the api 
More precisely, I used there template literal as ${category} in the api and want to implement different category such as sports, science, business with only using the category keyword.